# Sharepoint ClientContext usage in services

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dependency-injection

I use the SharePoint SDK in one of our WCF services.

To get a byte array (document) from SharePoint I use the ClientContext class of the SDK. The calls to SharePoint are all wrapped in a custom class called SharePointConnector(like a sort of repository pattern).

My goal is to inject the SharePointConnector class in my wcf service by using an interface ISharePointConnector.

My questions:

1. Should I create the ClientContext in the constructor of SharePointConnector or should use it per call, wrapped in a using block ? Concerns that I have: is it an expensive call to create the ClientContext ? Thread safe when multiple calls are made on the same instance of clientContext member variable?
2. At what point should I register the url so that it can be used in the constructor of ClientContext ?

Note that by implementing it by creating the ClientContext instance in the constructor, there is a difficulty to get the url that is required to create an instance of the ClientContext because the constructor injection by the DI container....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would very much recommend you to use the `ClientContext` within the scope of the Methods (or whatever calls are in your case) and not instanciating it in the constructor, mainly for two reasons:

1. **Flexibility:** You will be able to adjust the `ClientContext` to your needs in a given situation.
2. **Resources:** As you already pointed out, the `ClientContext` implements the `IDisposable` interface and should therefore be disposed/released after using it, this will save you some resources. You know the drill:

   `using (ClientContext clientCtx = new ClientContext(siteUrl)){ //do your stuff... }`